On a certain covering of the connect sum of Enriques surfaces
This is a soft question which is inspired by this one Show that $S^2 \times S^1$ is a double cover for the connected sum $\mathbb{RP}^3 \# \mathbb{RP^3}$..
Let $M$ be an Enriques surface, consider the manifold $N  =M \# M$. Then $\pi_{1}(N) = \mathbb{Z}_{2} * \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ with generators $a,b$, consider the subgroup $H \subset \pi_{1}(N)$ generated by $ab$, it is infinite cyclic of index $2$. Let $Y$ be the $4$-manifold which is the covering corresponding to this subgroup.
(soft) Question: Is $Y$ anything familiar?
Remark (+ correction): $\chi(Y) = 44$, in particular $Y$ is not an $S^1$-bundle. Is  there is an $S^1$-bundle in the connect sum decomp of $Y$?
Any relevant remarks are welcome.

Interesting questions. If you don't get any answers here, this might be a good math overflow question.

Thanks!, I got slightly less excited when I realised the Euler characteristic is huge, but sure maybe I will ask on MO. Also, on reflection, could have taken $M$ as the Grassmannian of real planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which has Euler characteristic $2$ and $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}_2$ therefore the corresponding $Y$ has Euler characteristic $4$, maybe there is more likely to be nice geometry happening.

Keep in mind, though, that there may be no better description of $M # M$ than $M # M$. In 3-dimensions (at least) that is actually the default; it's kind of a coincidence that $\mathbb RP^3 # \mathbb RP^3$ has another "name".
